# How can I use gradle versions file for multimodule gradle app?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, multi-module

I have a composite project with a structure like:

```
--+ composite
  |    |
  |    +- gradle
  |
  +-- application1
  |    |
  |    +- gradle
  |
  +-- application2
  |    |
  |    +- gradle
  |
  +-- application3
  |    |
  |    +- gradle
```

Each gradle dir has it's own libs.versions.toml file, but i want to make a single one under the root (composite) to maintain the dependency versions it a centralized way.

How can I lik the version from root file?

For example, I'm adding dependency at `build.gradle.kts` file at `application1` like `implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:${rootProject.libs.versions.openapi.get()}")`, but i can't access root properties - only ext.

I'm not quite experienced at such cases. Could anyone please help with this?

Comment: What does your settings.gradle file have? You hint that this is a composite build rather than using subprojects.  I think that makes a significant difference, as composite builds are not considered subprojects and won't have access to the root the way you are expecting..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using subprojects, it should work to reference the catalog of the root project.  If you are using composite builds, try specifying the version catalog file for each project explicitly.

See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sec:sharing-catalogs

Use this for each project in the composite build - adjust the path as needed so all projects share the same file:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        libs {
            from(files("../gradle/libs.versions.toml"))
        }
    }
}
```